# Basic step in sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I start learning convergence of series and I do not understand the following step.

$$\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty}\left ( 2n+1 \right )x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( x^{2n+1} \right )$$

I know that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\propto }x^{n}=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
but here I have n=0, so I will convert it in the way that: $$x\sum_{n=0}^{\propto }x^{2n}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\propto }x^{2n-2}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\propto }x^{2n}= \frac{x}{1-x^{2}}$$
 What after a derivation is: $$\frac{1+x^{2}}{\left ( 1-x^{2} \right )^{2}}$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty}\left ( 2n+1 \right )x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( x^{2n+1} \right )'?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true in general, we have that by differentiation for $|x|<1$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( x^{2n+1} \right ) \implies f'(x)=\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty}\left ( 2n+1 \right )x^{2n}$$

and

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( x^{2n+1} \right )=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(x^2)^n$$

Comment: One should add that this doesn't hold for all x. Only in the domain of convergence.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Yes of course, that's absolutely a lack in the answer! I fix that. Thanks

Comment: @user so, if I want to find the sum of series, first I have to integrate it?

Comment: @Shelley I've added a step more, we need just to use geometric series. Try by yourself to obtain the result.

Comment: @Shelley You can add that editing your question, we'll take a look to it.

Comment: @user i that correct?

Comment: @Shelley More simply we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }r^n=\frac1{1-r} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(x^2)^n=\frac1{1-x^2} $$

Comment: @Shelley Your step is not correct we have indeed $$x\sum_{n=0}^{\propto }x^{2n}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\propto }x^{2n-2}$$

Comment: @user Yes, okay I can see it, I did it wrongly, but then if I correct myself, I will get $\frac{x}{1-x^{2}}$ and the final result, so the sum of the series will be its derivation, so: $\frac{1+x^{2}}{\left ( 1-x^{2} \right )^{2}}$?

Comment: @Shelley It seems you are loosing an $x$ factor to me. You could add your derivation in your question.

Comment: @user Could you check it?

Comment: @Shelley Yes that's fine! You should revise the first equality which is wrong according to the work you carried out.

Comment: @user okay, thanks.. just one more question, if I have to find the sum of the series, the possible path is to find tha integration series and transform into something I know the sum of, and then make the derivation and that is it?

Comment: @Shelley This is often the case when you can relate two series by derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's see: both series converge only for $\;|x|<1\;$ , so for these values we get on the right side:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n+1}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}=\frac x{1-x^2}$$

and on the other side

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)x^{2n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}=2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{2n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}=$$

$$=x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\right)'+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}=\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2}+\frac1{1-x^2}$$

So unless this last function is zero, the equality is wrong. For example, input $\;x=\frac12\;$ in the last function...